# Some Problems in the book ‘A course in Probability Theory’, K.L. Chung

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

Q1.(page10.6) A point $x$ is said to belong to the support of the d.f.(distribution funtion) $F$  iff for every $\epsilon>0$ we have $F(x+\epsilon)-F(x-\epsilon)>0$. The set of all such $x$ is called the support of $F$. Show that ezch point of jump belongs to the support, and that each isolated point of the support is a point of jump. Give an example of a discrete d.f. whose support is the whole line.

I cannot show the second claim: each isolated point of the support is a point of jump.

Q2.(page12.3) If the support of a d.f. is of measure zero then $F$ is singular. The converse is false.

I just cannot construct a proper conterexample

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) Chung's example [Example 2. on the $3^d$ page]: Take an ordering of the rationals and assign the geometric distribution to the ordered set of rationals. Let $b_1=\frac{1}{2}, b_2=\frac{1}{4},...b_n=\frac{1}{2^{n}},...$, where $b_n$ is the mass assigned to the $n^{th}$ rational, $a_n$. All reals belong to the support of the corresponding $F$ because for any $\epsilon>0$ there are rationals in the interval $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)$, that is $F$ jumps infinitely many times within that interval. So the support of this $F$ is the whole real line.

(2) Chung's definition [$11^{th}\ page]$ ]: A function is singular iff it is not identically zero and its derivative exits and is zero a.e.

Chung' theorem [$1.3.1 (a)$, $12^{th}$] page: If a function is increasing, tends to zero if $x$ tends to the $-\infty$, and is bounded then its derivative exists a.e. (${+\infty}$ as a value of the derivative is allowed.)

Chung's example above describes such a function: it is monotonously increasing and bounded, and tends to zero  if $x$ goes to the $-\infty$, that is its derivative exists a.e. The derivative is zero at irrational points (**this I cannot prove but having read Chung's first chapter I cannot get to any other conclusion.**) and is ${+\infty}$ at the rationals. That is, we have a singular function whose support is the whole real line even if it is singular.

$$Edited$$

The definition of singularity is given above. As far as discreteness: Chung says on the $10^{th}$ page "A plausible definition of a discrete d.f. may be given us: >>It is a d.f. that has jumps and is constant between the jumps<<." This means that the derivative is a.e. zero since there are only countably many jumps. That is, such a d.f. is singular.

Comment: Thanks! I am wondering if we could first prove exercise 6(page13), that is, "a discrete distribution is singular".

Comment: @Henry: I added the required explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The edited solution posted by zoli is only valid when the discrete d.f. is "discrete in the Euclidian topology" - that is, if all jump points are isolated. Question 5 on page 10 asks the reader to describe why that "plausible definition" is *incorrect*. It is not correct because the jump points may be dense in ℝ, in which case any two jump points will have a jump point in between, so "constant between jumps" doesn't make sense.

If the jump points are dense, then it is not immediate that a discrete d.f. is singular. How do we know that those jumps approaching each number in ℝ do not induce a positive derivative?

To see that it is singular, take the following facts from the text.

If $F$ is a d.f. then $F$ may be written as $$F = F_{ac} + F_s$$ where $F_s$ is singular, and $$0 <= F_{ac}(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x}F'(t)dt <= F(x)$$

Then, let $F$ be a discrete d.f. and fix $\epsilon > 0$. Let $\{ a_i \}$ be an enumeration of all jump sizes. Since $F$ is discrete, $$ \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}a_i = 1 $$ and there is some $N$ such that $$ \sum_{i = 1}^{N}a_i > 1 - \epsilon $$
Let $J = \sum_{i = 1}^{N} a_i\delta_i$ where $\delta_i$ is the point-mass function defined in the text for constructing discrete d.f.'s. Since $N$ is finite, $J$ is, in fact, "discrete in the Euclidian topology", with constant values between isolated jump points, so $J' = 0$ almost everywhere.

Now, let $G = F - J$, essentially F without the jump points which bring it within $\epsilon$ of 1, so $G(x) < \epsilon$ for all $x$ and: $$F_{ac}(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x}F'(t)dt = \int_{-\infty}^{x}G'(t)dt + \int_{-\infty}^{x}J'(t)dt = \int_{-\infty}^{x}G'(t)dt + 0 <= G(x) < \epsilon$$ $\epsilon$ and $x$ are arbitrary and $F_{ac} >= 0$, so $F_{ac} = 0$.

From the above, $F = F_{ac} + F_s = 0 + F_s$, which is singular, which proves Q6.

Finally, the counter-example to the converse in Q2 is a discrete d.f. which is dense in some subset, $S$ of ℝ where $m(S) > 0$.